# vba selenium sending keys

Tags: vba, selenium, sendkeys

I am trying to data scrape LinkedIn page. I successfully sign in, input search value to inputbox, but after cannot send key enter. Code is below. I think there was something like for enter sendkeys. "~". Whats is interesting why the code like webdriver.sendkeys("inputvalue",keys.enter) gives an error?

```
Sub LinkdNIn_SlnIUM_login()

Dim webdriber As WebDriver
    Set webdriber = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/"
    
    webdriber.Start "chrome", URL
    webdriber.Get "/"
    webdriber.Wait 3000
    
    On Error Resume Next
Dim a As WebElements
    Set a = webdriber.FindElementsByClass("authwall-join-form__form-toggle--bottom")
    a.Item(1).Click

    Set a = webdriber.FindElementsById("session_key")
    a.First.Click
    a.First.SendKeys Worksheets(1).Range("I6").Value
    
    webdriber.Wait 3000
    Set a = webdriber.FindElementsById("session_password")
    a.Item(1).Click
    webdriber.Wait 3000
    a.First.SendKeys Worksheets(1).Range("I7").Value
    webdriber.Wait 3000
    Set a = webdriber.FindElementsByClass("sign-in-form__submit-button")
    a.Item(1).Click
    webdriber.Wait 3000
    Set a = webdriber.FindElementsByClass("secondary-action")
    a.Item(1).Click
    webdriber.Wait 3000
    Set a = webdriber.FindElementsByClass("search-global-typeahead__collapsed-search-button")
    a.Item(1).Click
    webdriber.Wait 3000
    Set a = webdriber.FindElementsByClass("search-global-typeahead__input")
    a.Item(1).Click
    webdriber.Wait 3000
    a.Item(1).SendKeys ("data analyst in jobs")
    a.Item(1).SendKeys Keys.Enter ' error object is required
End Sub
```

I tried with no result;

```
a.Item(1).SendKeys ("data analyst in jobs")
webdriber.Wait 3000
a.Item(1).SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
a.Item(1).SendKeys ("data analyst in jobs" & vbCrLf)
```